# Finding a dataset to benchmark cryptographic algorithms

Tags: encryption, blocksize, decryption

I’m planning to compare cryptographic algorithms in terms of encryption/decryption time, memory used etc. and for that I’m in need of a standard dataset consisting of plaintexts of different bit sizes and character lengths. Can anyone suggest a source where I can obtain these data?

Comment: The value of the data shouldn't matter for cryptographic purposes. Also you might want to have a look at [SUPERCOP](https://bench.cr.yp.to/supercop.html).

Comment: @SEJPM: I don't agree. I would agree if you said something like *for a good cryptographic algorithm and its good implementation* the value of data should not matter. But there are algorithms and implementations of different quality, some providing much information via side channels. May be it is a purpose of the author to compare them also from this point of view.

Comment: @SEJPM: Can you please clarify your comment? Does that mean we can use a random dataset as we wish to calculate the required information ?